# This method must return a result of type String, Java, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a method I am writing which needs to return a type string, as it feeds into a .toString. The code is below.  As far as I can tell, it will always return type String. But Eclipse still says I am wrong. Can someone help me?

```
public String getRevenue() {
    Integer Revenue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getNumberRooms(); ++i) {
        if (roomsArray[i].isOccupied() == false) {
            Revenue = (roomsArray[i].getRate() + Revenue);
        }
    }
    return "$" + Revenue.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you saved this file?  Are you sure the error is not before this method?

Comment: what's the error eclipse is showing?

Comment: Code looks okay, couple of things
1. toString is not needed here as you are concatenating with a string so compiler will do the conversation automatically
2. Follow Java naming conventions  so ideally Revenue should be revenue. It improves readability and maintainability

Comment: It is highlighting the line reporting "This method must return a result of type String".  I haven't actually run or tested the file yet, building the test class now.  But it should always return a string from what I can tell, even if the loop doesn't run because the number of rooms is 0.

Comment: what is the return type of roomsArray[i].getRate() ?

Comment: If you have a compile error, then there is no point at all running the code.  As I asked before - have you saved these changes?  Secondly is there some method before this that is maybe not coded correctly?

Answer (score -1):

So turns out once I actually ran the code, the error went away.  Still new to Eclipse.  Thanks to all responses. I have cleaned up the code some to keep it properly standard.  Mostly just changed Revenue to revenue.

```
public String getRevenue() {
    Integer revenue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getNumberRooms(); ++i) {
        if (roomsArray[i].isOccupied() == false) {
            revenue = (roomsArray[i].getRate() + revenue);
        }
    }
    return "$" + revenue;
```

Comment: As said by others the file was likely not saved. Sometimes JDT messes up though; make sure _Project > Build Automatically_ is checked and use _Project > Clean..._ to force a rebuild: it usually fixes lasting error markers